# Wordpress posts backgrounds opacity changing on hover

Tags: html, css, wordpress, background-color, styling

My default posts background need to be darker on default (0.3 of black) and 0.2 of black on hover.
Heres the preview: http://polishcreep.stronazen.pl/
My post loop:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' );?>
<div id="post" style="height:460px; background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); background-size:cover; width:100%; margin:0; background-image: url('<?php echo $thumb['0'];?>')">
<div id="date_holder">
 <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-inverse"></i>
<?php the_time('j F Y') ?> 
</div>
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
 <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
  <div class="entry">
  </div>
 </div>
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

It would also be great if you could help me positioning the date and title. I need it to look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aaln.jpg

I also need to get rid of these white borders, already set the backgrounds to be 100% width.

My CSS:

```
#post {
height: 460px;
width:100%;
background-size: cover;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
margin:0;

}
#post:hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#date_holder{
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
margin-left:400px;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-size:16px;
padding:5px;
}
h2 {
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:32px;
padding:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is to add overlay by pseudo-element. Try to do this:

```
#post{
  position: relative;
}
#post:before{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#post:before:hover{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

to positin date and title try to put yout content in container and play with that.

```
.container{
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

to get rid of borders , use

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

Pozdrawiam !:)